# Terraform - Global Route 53 , Multiple Environments

Tags: terraform, amazon-route53, global

TL;DR I have three environments (dev, test, prod).  How do I have them all reference the same `aws_route53_zone` and just append to it.

Hello Folks,

I'm using Terraform for a side project.  In my project, I have three environments dev,test, prod.  All three groups will be under the same hosted zone.  The goal is to have test.foo.com, dev.foo.com, and foo.com.

As of now, my directory structure looks like this:

```
Project Folder
  env
    |--dev
    |   |--dev-main.tf
    |   |--dev-backends.tf
    |   |--dev-output.tf
    |   |--dev-variables.tf
    |--test...
    |--prod...
  modules
  |--cognito
  |--s3
  |--iam
```

Any help on referencing the same zone under all three environments is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the `aws_route53_zone` data source? Does that not achieve what you want? If not can you explain what is missing from your usage of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating another environment and calling it `global`.

```
Project Folder
  env
    |---
    |--global
    |---
    |--dev
    |   |--dev-main.tf
    |   |--dev-backends.tf
    |   |--dev-output.tf
    |   |--dev-variables.tf
    |--test...
    |--prod...
  modules
  |--cognito
  |--s3
  |--iam
```

In that environment, I created my top zone.  In my environments of dev/test/prod, I reference the output of the global using `terraform_remote_state`.  It looks like this:

```
File:dev-main.tf

data "terraform_remote_state" "global_route53" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket  = "my_global_output_bucket"
    key     = "StateLockID"
    region  = "us-east-2"
  }
}
....
module "acm" {
  zone_id = data.terraform_remote_state.global_route53.outputs.main_zone_id
}
```

Hope this helps the next person that runs across this.